# If i request email permission, will i ever NOT get a user's email address?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

I am using the Graph API and able to get users' email addresses successfully.

I am wondering if i can assume that i will ALWAYS get a user's email address back, or if i need to plan for some fringe scenario where the user's permissions are set or something and i will be unable to get the user's email address.

Thanks.

Comment: @Forty-Two defensive coding is great, but when the defensive solution requires a revised design that adds non-trivial development time across a few different platforms plus testing time "just in case," i'd like to weigh my options

Answer (score 1):

As long as you ask for the `email` permission and that the user accept it, you'll **always** get the user email. However, you'll need to foresee the case where the user don't accept it.

Comment: Also the case, when user have not shared his/her email with anyone. Rare but can happen, so code defensively as Forty-Two said.

Comment: No. In that case, the API will still be able to retrieve the email.

Comment: But still, some users have incurred the "blank" email issue but not sure why. Ref: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61

Comment: That's what i'm not clear on - if i request an access token like: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?%20type=user_agent&%20client_id=394824653139531&%20redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&%20scope=email the FB dialog says the app will get access to my basic info and email and i can either login or cancel.  it's not like "online presence" where it's a permission the user can deny - it's all or nothing.   where is the case where i would get an access token but no email?